# area of ellipse in different quadrants

Tags: conic-sections

Let the equation of the ellipse $\displaystyle \frac{(x-20)^2}{20}+\frac{(y-16)^2}{16}=2016$.  Let $R_1$, $R_2$, $R_3$, $R_4$ denote the area of the ellipse in first, second, third and fourth quadrants respectively, then $R_1-R_2+R_3-R_4$ equals—

From the problem it is clear that the major axis of the ellipse is $\sqrt{20\times2016}$ units and the minor axis is $4\sqrt{2016}$ units.  The centre of the ellipse is $(20,16)$ and too bad, the ellipse is not symmetrical about any axis.  I tried solving this question using integration but the integration too seemed too cumbersome and lengthy.  This is a question asked in some entrance test hence it should have a fast solution indeed.  Please help me out.  Many thanks!

Comment: It seems to be elliptic version of [this problem](http://gogeometry.com/problem/p578_chords_90_degrees_area_math_ed.htm), but I can't think of the proof at this moment.

Comment: Can you provide a link to this entrance test? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering $$\frac{(x-h)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(y-k)^2}{b^2}=1$$

where $h,k>0$.

Let $x_{+}$, $x_{-}$ be the $x$-intercepts and $y_{+}$, $y_{-}$ be the $y$-intercepts

where $x_{-}<0<x_{+}$, $y_{-}<0<y_{+}$

> **By doing simple dissection of the ellipse below:**
>
> The red and blue regions below are confined in the region of $0<x<x_{+}+x_{-}$

[image]

> The purple region below is confined in the region of $0<y<y_{+}+y_{-}$

[image]

> Hence the required area is 
>   \begin{align*}
>   R_{1}-R_{2}+R_{3}-R_{4} &= (x_{+}+x_{-})(y_{+}+y_{-}) \\
>   &=(2h)(2k) \\
>   &= 4hk
> \end{align*}
>
> In general, it holds for any $h$ and $k$ such that $\displaystyle \frac{h^2}{a^2}+\frac{k^2}{b^2}<1$.